# codeigniter calendar: how to get the selected date?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to modify codeigniter calendar in order to give a separate add button for every cell. when the add button clicked pop up will be displayed with the particular date auto filled in that pop up. For that i want to get the selected date when i click the add button.

My calendar is like this.
[image]

I used following model function to create the calendar

```
function mycal_model() {   

 $this->conf = array(
        'show_next_prev' => True,
        'next_prev_url' => base_url() . 'index.php/dashboard/index/'
    );

    $this->conf['template'] = '
        {table_open}<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="calendar">{/table_open}

        {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

        {heading_previous_cell}<th class="prev_sign"><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
        {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
        {heading_next_cell}<th class="next_sign"><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

        {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

        //Deciding where to week row start
        {week_row_start}<tr class="week_name" >{/week_row_start}
        //Deciding  week day cell and  week days
        {week_day_cell}<td >{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
        //week row end
        {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

        {cal_row_start}<tr class= "days">{/cal_row_start}
        {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

        {cal_cell_content}
            <div class="day_num">{day}<button type="button" class="add_btn">+</button>                
            </div>
            <div class="content" style="width:50%; height:40px;">{content}                
            </div>

        {/cal_cell_content}

        {cal_cell_content_today}
        <div class="day_num highlight">{day}<button type="button" class="add_btn">+</button>
        </div>
         <div class= "content">{content}</div>
        {/cal_cell_content_today}

        {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num">{day}<button type="button" class="add_btn">+</button>
        </div>
            <div class="content1" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>
            <div class="content2" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>               
            </div>
            <div class="content3" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>
            <div class="content4" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left;; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>          
        {/cal_cell_no_content}
        {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day}<button type="button" class="add_btn">+</button>
        </div>
            <div class="content1" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>
            <div class="content2" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>               
            </div>
            <div class="content3" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>
            <div class="content4" style="width:50%; height:35px; display:block; float:left;; background-color:#95FF95; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;  "><a href="#">+</a>                
            </div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

        {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

        {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
        {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

        {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';
}
```

I have the following script for the button click event for the add button. but i can show only the pop up.i have no idea how to get the selected date.

```
 $(".calendar .days td .add_btn").click(function() {               
                $('#events_add_modal').modal('show');

            });
```

If anyone has an idea that would be a great help.

Comment: Have you tried this.. ? http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP yes. I tried it earlier. But in that calendar we cannot divide a cell into four sections. I wanted this to divide into four sections. That is the requirement. That is why i used this instead of full calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the video on [this page](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-the-calendar-library--net-9570). He's using jquery at about 30 mins in the video to build an onClick event which returns the day that was clicked. It's easy to expand to return the full date.

Hope you'll find it useful.